# Prevent users from directly creating cases of a certain record type

Tags: apex, visualforce, case

I have many different record types for cases. Some cases are special cases that can ONLY be created through a certain action on a VisualForce page. I don't want users to create them directly through the application. How do I go about this in Salesforce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend that you make the Record Type unavailable to all profiles. That will prevent the users from creating records with (or changing them to) that Record Type.

Once that is done, in your VF controller you can query for the ID of said RT and apply it in code to the records created in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Sebastian Kessel's approved answer: in my case that would mean making all Record Types unavailable to certain profiles. Which is impossible, Salesforce needs a default Record Type for a profile.

How I solved this: I introduced a new Checkbox field 'Created via appropriate way', which is not shown anywhere. Default value false. I then made sure that the buttons/software that create the proper cases set this field to true.

The final step is to have a validation rule that ensures that for certain profiles, and maybe some other conditions, the Checkbox must be true when creating a case.